# Account datagrid duplicate rows

Tags: orocrm

I'm using OroCRM 2.6.19, and for some reason, when I go to page `/account`, my datagrid is duplicating some rows:

[Duplicate record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVBg5.jpg)

As you can see in the image above, Oro counts one record, but shows 2 rows, with the same ID.

I tried to add distinct flag through EventListener, with onBuildAfter method, but it did not work:

```
public function onBuildAfter(BuildAfter $event)
{
    $datagrid = $event->getDatagrid();
    $config = $datagrid->getConfig();
    $query = $config->getOrmQuery();

    $query->setDistinct();
}
```

My services.yml:

```
services:
    my_company_account.event_listener.datagrid.set_distinct_to_account_grid:
        class: Company\Bundle\CompanyAccountBundle\EventListener\Datagrid\SetDistinctToAccountGrid
        arguments:
            - "@oro_security.token_accessor"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oro_datagrid.datagrid.build.after.accounts-grid, method: onBuildAfter }
```

How can I show only one record? If I'm implementing the wrong event, can you help me implement the right one?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing and a bit of luck, I found that, for some reason, the Contact associated with the Account had **two primary phones** in the database. Then, due to the join made to build the datagrid, the results ended up appearing duplicated.

Anyway, thanks, guys!

Comment: It looks like an issue in the contact creation, import, or editing process. There should be only one primary phone for a single contact. I recommend checking your customizations around that to eliminate the risk, as many features rely on the fact that there is only one primary phone. These features could work unexpectedly when there is more than one primary phone.